# Override the color of a airlinesection when entering insert mode

Tags: colorscheme, plugin-airline

I want to override a section in airline with my own color when I enter insert mode. Im using the PlugIn pencil and I want to change the color of PencilMode.

This is the section I want to override.

```
let g:airline_section_x = '%{PencilMode()}'
```

[image]

It should look like this:

Has anybody any idea how to switch to orange with white text when entering indert mode? I did not find any information about.

Thank you